# How to set up a log4j.properties file for sub packages

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to create log file for two packages: `net.biomodels.jummp.indexing` and `net.biomodels.jummp.indexing.solrindexer`. However, it does not work as I expect. The log only contains what are involving in `net.biomodels.jummp.indexing` package.
Could you help me finding out the missing of the following logging configuration?

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, R

# everything goes to the general log
log4j.logger.net.biomodels.jummp.indexing=DEBUG, stdout, R
log4j.additivity.net.biomodels.jummp.indexing=false

# I want to log classes in solrindexer package, underneath indexing package
log4j.logger.net.biomodels.jummp.indexing.solrindexer=INFO, stdout, R
log4j.additivity.net.biomodels.jummp.indexing.solrindexer=false

## general log
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=logs/general.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %t %d{ISO8601} %c{2} - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is fine from a syntax point of view. I suspect your log level is the problem. You have your first logger set to DEBUG level:

`log4j.logger.net.biomodels.jummp.indexing=`**DEBUG**`, stdout, R`

while your second logger is set to INFO level:

`log4j.logger.net.biomodels.jummp.indexing.solrindexer=`**INFO**`, stdout, R`

Thus if you are expecting to see DEBUG level logs from classes in the package `net.biomodels.jummp.indexing.solrindexer` you will not see them unless you change the log level of your logger to DEBUG or lower.